# How to delete webapp created using Epiphany?

Tags: webapps, epiphany

How can I delete a webapp that I have created using the Epiphany browser?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Open Epiphany web browser.
2. Type "about:applications" as URL and press Enter.
3. Delete the web app.

It is good to bookmark "about:applications" for future use.

Comment: Its interesting to add about:applications as a web-app :)

Comment: @deshmukh Yes! Do that if you don't want to come here again. ;)